# Почему возможна подмена значений в сообщениях при передаче по локальной сети?

Tags: c, сеть, клиент-сервер

На языке С реализую сетевой чат. Отлаживал его на одной виртуальной машине, в разных терминалах все работает как нужно, но при подключении у серверу с идентичным скриптом, но на другой машине, скрипт перестает работать корректно. С первого раза значения считываются как следует, но потом клиент считывает какие-то непредсказуемые данные. Не понимаю как такое может быть, если скрипт буквально один и тот же.

Брандмаузер отключен, да и даже если бы был включен, я установил разрешение на обоих машинах на используемый порт. На обоих стоит аналогичная версия ubuntu и аналогичная версия Virtual Box.

С чем такое может быть связано?

Сервер:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PORT 9876
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define MAX_CONNECTIONS 5
#define REGISTRATION '1'
#define CHECKINFO '2'
#define SENDMESSAGE '3'
#define EXIT '4'

struct Node {
    char name[30];
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* createNode(char* name) {
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
      newNode->name[i] = name[i];
    }
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}


struct Message {  
  int id;
  char from[30];
  char to[30];
    char message[BUFFER_SIZE];
    struct Message* next;
};

struct Message* createMessage(char* from, char* to, char* message, int id) {
    struct Message* mes = (struct Message*)malloc(sizeof(struct Message));
    mes->id = id;
    memcpy(mes->from, from, 30);
    memcpy(mes->to, to, 30);
    memcpy(mes->message, message, BUFFER_SIZE);
    mes->next = NULL;
    return mes;
}


void pushBackMessage(struct Message** headRef, char* from, char* to, char* message, int id) {
    struct Message* newNode = createMessage(from, to, message, id);
    if (*headRef == NULL) {
        *headRef = newNode;
        return;
    }
    struct Message* temp = *headRef;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newNode;
}

void DeleteMessage(struct Message** headRef, int id)
{
  struct Message* temp = *headRef;
  struct Message* prev = temp;
  
  if (temp->id == id) 
  {
    *headRef = temp->next;
    return;
  }
  while (temp != NULL) 
  {
    if (temp->id == id) 
    {
        prev->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}

void CheckMessage(struct Message** headRef, char* to, int socket, char* buffer)
{
  struct Message* temp = *headRef;
  
  while (temp != NULL) 
  {
    if (strcmp(temp->to, to) == 0) 
    {
      buffer[0] = '[';
      int lastind;
        for(int i = 0; i<BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
        {
          if (temp->from[i] == '\n'  temp->from[i] == (char)0)
          {
            buffer[i+1] = ']';
            buffer[i+2] = ':';
            buffer[i+3] = '\t';
            lastind = i+4;
            break;
          }
          buffer[i+1] = temp->from[i];
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i<BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
        {
          if (temp->message[i] == '\n'  temp->message[i] == (char)0)
          {
            buffer[lastind+i] = '\n';
            buffer[lastind+i+1] = (char)0;
            send(socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
            break;
          }
          buffer[lastind+i] = temp->message[i];
        }
    }
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  buffer[0] = (char)0;
  send(socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
  memset(buffer, (char)0, BUFFER_SIZE);
}


void CleanStdin()
{
  char c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
}


void pushBack(struct Node** headRef, char* name) {
    struct Node* newNode = createNode(name);
    if (*headRef == NULL) {
        *headRef = newNode;
        return;
    }
    struct Node* temp = *headRef;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newNode;
}

void Delete(struct Node** headRef, char* name)
{
  struct Node* temp = *headRef;
  struct Node* prev = temp;
  char buf[31];
  buf[30] = (char)0;
  memcpy(buf, name, 30);
  if (strcmp(temp->name, buf) == 0) 
  {
    *headRef = temp->next;
    return;
  }
  while (temp != NULL) 
  {
    if (strcmp(temp->name, name) == 0) 
    {
        prev->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}

int Find(struct Node** headRef, char* name)
{
  struct Node* temp = *headRef;
  while (temp != NULL) 
  {
    if (strcmp(temp->name, name) == 0) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  return 0;
}

void PrintUsers(struct Node** headRef, int sock, int usersVal, char* buffer)
{
  struct Node* temp = *headRef;
  for (int i = 0; i < usersVal; i++) 
  {
    memcpy(buffer, temp->name, 30);
    send(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}


  pthread_t thread_id;
  pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
  struct Node* head = NULL;
  struct Message* meshead = NULL;
    int server_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    int usersVal = 0, mesVal = 0;

void* mainFunc(void * arg)
{
  int new_socket = (int)arg;
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  char name[30];
  // Чтение сообщения от клиента
    while(1)
    {
      memset(buffer, (char)0, BUFFER_SIZE);

      //pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      CheckMessage(&meshead, name, new_socket, buffer);
      
      //Check operation
    recv(new_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    char operation = buffer[0];
    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    if ( operation == REGISTRATION)
    {
      recv(new_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
      memcpy(name, buffer, 30);
      int RegCode;
      if (Find(&head, name) == 1)
      {
        printf("User already registered: %s", name);
        RegCode = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        printf("User successfully registered: %s", name);
        pushBack(&head, name);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        usersVal++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        RegCode = 0;
      }
      memcpy(buffer, &RegCode, 4);
      send(new_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
      
    }
    else if (operation == CHECKINFO) 
    {
      //pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      memcpy(buffer, &usersVal, 4);
      send(new_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);


      PrintUsers(&head, new_socket, usersVal, buffer);
      //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      
    }
    
    else if (operation == SENDMESSAGE) 
    {
      recv(new_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
      char mesName[30];
      memcpy(mesName, buffer, 30);
      printf("\nName %s\n", mesName);
      int FindCode;
      if(Find(&head, mesName) == 1)
      {  
        FindCode = 1;
        memcpy(buffer, &FindCode, 4);
        send(new_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
      }
      else
      {
        FindCode = 0;
        memcpy(buffer, &FindCode, 4);
        send(new_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        continue;
      }
      //read message
      recv(new_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
      mesVal++;
      pushBackMessage(&meshead, name, mesName, buffer, mesVal);
      printf("message: %s\n", buffer);
    }
    
    else if (operation == EXIT)
    {
      close(new_socket);
      printf("\nExited!\n");
      Delete(&head, name);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      usersVal--;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      CleanStdin();
      
      break;
    }
    
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  
  int new_socket;
    // Создание сокета
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
      
    // Присваивание опции сокету (можно повторно использовать адрес)
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
      
    // Привязка сокета к адресу и порту
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Ожидание входящих соединений
    if (listen(server_fd, MAX_CONNECTIONS) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Принятие входящего соединения
    while(1)
    {
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) 
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    printf("\nConnected!\n");
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, mainFunc, (void*)new_socket);
  }
    return 0;

}
```

Клиент

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SERVER_ADDRESS "192.168.1.83"
#define SERVER_PORT 9876
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define REGISTRATION '1'
#define CHECKINFO '2'
#define SENDMESSAGE '3'
#define EXIT '4'

int Socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
{
  int sock = socket(domain, type, protocol);
  if (sock < 0) {
        perror("Failed to create socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return sock;
}

void Inet_pton(int af, const char *src, void *dst)
{
  if (inet_pton(af, src, dst) <= 0) {
        perror("Invalid server address");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
}

void Connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen)
{
  if (connect(sockfd, addr, addrlen) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to connect to server");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void Send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags)
{
  if (send(sockfd, buf, len, flags) < 0) 
    {
      perror("Failed to send message to server");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void Recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags)
{
  if (recv(sockfd, buf, len, flags) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to receive message from server");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

// Создание сокета и подключение к серверу
int Conn()
{
  int sock = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    Inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_ADDRESS, &server_address.sin_addr);
    Connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    return sock;
}

void CleanStdin()
{
  char c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
}


int main() {
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  char symb, operation;
  int sock = Conn();
  Recv(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
  buffer[0] = REGISTRATION;
  Send(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
  printf("\nEnter Name: ");
  fgets(buffer, 30, stdin);
  Send(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
  int RegCode;
  Recv(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
  memcpy(&RegCode, buffer, 4);
  
  if (RegCode == 1)
  {
    printf("You was registered before");
  }
  else if (RegCode == 0)
  {
    printf("You were successfully registered");
  }
    while(1)
    {
    CleanStdin();
     while(1)
    {
      Recv(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
      if(buffer[0] == (char)0)
      {
        break;
      }
      printf("%s", buffer);
    }
    printf("\n1. Get users info");
    printf("\n2. Send message");
    printf("\n3. Exit\n");
    symb = getchar();
    switch (symb)
    {
      case '1':
      {
        buffer[0] = CHECKINFO;
        Send(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        int usersVal;
        Recv(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        memcpy(&usersVal, buffer, 4);
        printf("\nAmount of users = %d\n", usersVal);
        for(int i = 0; i < usersVal; i++)
        {
          char name[30];
          Recv(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
          memcpy(name, buffer, 30);
          printf("\nUser: %s\n", name);
        }
        break;
      }
      case '2':
      {
        buffer[0] = SENDMESSAGE;
        Send(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        CleanStdin();
        printf("\nEnter Name: ");
        fgets(buffer, 30, stdin);
        Send(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        int FindCode;
        Recv(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        memcpy(&FindCode, buffer, 4);
        if(FindCode != 1)
        {
          printf("\nUser doesn't exists");
          break;
        }
        memset(buffer, (char)0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        printf("\nEnter message: ");
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        Send(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        break;
      }
      
      case '3':
      {
        printf("Exiting...\n");
        buffer[0] = EXIT;
        Send(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        exit(0);
      }
    }
  }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Без образцов релевантного кода ничего сказать нельзя

Comment: Подумал что есть какое то очевидное объяснение, ведь код вел себя адекватно, но все таки добавил.

Comment: Вам надо на стороне сервера у recv/send возвращаемое значчение получать, проверять и использовать. Кстати, на стороне клиента тоже, не только на -1 проверять. Дело в том, что при передаче по сети совершенно не обязательно вы будете получать одним recv-ом все отправленные send-ом BUFFER_SIZE байт за один раз

Answer (score 0):

По совету из комментария проблема была решена. Стоило всего лишь добавить на стороне клиента в функции получения сообщения проверку на полученное количество байт, и если оно было меньше нужного, принять сообщение повторно.

```
void Recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags)
{
  int res = recv(sockfd, buf, len, flags);
  if (res < 0) {
        perror("Failed to receive message from server");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  while (res < BUFFER_SIZE)
  {
       int diff = BUFFER_SIZE - res;
       res += recv(sockfd, buf + res, diff, flags);
  }
}
```

Целесообразно сделать так же при приеме сообщения, однако это все равно вызывает ошибки время от времени. Самое эффективное что удалось сделать это уменьшить размер буфера с 1024 до 150 байт. В таком случае сообщения чаще успевают доставляться за один раз

Comment: Это тоже будет работать не правильно, перетирая при последующем приеме данные, прочитанные за первый прием.

Comment: Для начала почитайте [man 7 tcp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html), потом (на всякий случай) посмотрите [man 2 poll](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (или select), возможно вы пересмотрите архитектуру своей программы

Comment: @user7860670 , да, поправил, теперь должно быть как надо

Comment: в цикле while нет проверки ошибок. будет зависон